# Cucumber test suite with Capybara and Chromedriver hangs

Tags: macos, selenium, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have a cucumber test suite which fails to run since I have moved to a new computer.

The test suite uses `Capybara (v1.1.2)`, `Chrome Driver (v26.0.1383.0)` and `Selenium-Webdriver (v2.27.1)` to run JavaScript tests in Chrome.

Every test hangs with Chrome's blue "aw snap" of death. If I kill the current test run with `CTRL-C` the next test runs and also fails.

I am at a complete loss. This exact same test suite runs fine on Circle CI and on a colleagues Mac.

I have also tried swapping out **Chrome Driver** for other Capybara drivers **Phantom JS** and **Capybara Webkit**.

Phantom JS is a bit of a wipe out :(

Capybara Webkit gets a lot further but still fails many tests with: `Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)`

I think there is something fundamentally wrong with Webkit on my machine.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.

Any ideas at all?

**UPDATE**

**`features/support/env.rb`**

```
require 'cucumber/rails'

Capybara.default_selector = :css

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
  DatabaseCleaner.orm = 'mongoid'
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation

require 'minitest/spec'
World(MiniTest::Assertions)
MiniTest::Spec.new(nil)
```

**`features/support/chrome.rb`**

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

**`Gemfile`**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'font-awesome-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara' # provides integration_test generator
  gem 'capybara_minitest_spec' # provides RSpec-like matchers
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'debugger' # please only enable debugger when needed
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-matchers'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require  => false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy' # for save and open page
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'mocha', :require => false
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end

group :staging, :qa do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'thin'
gem 'ey_config'

gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'

gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-history', github: 'stengland/mongoid-history'
gem 'bson_ext'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'switch_user'

gem 'cancan'

gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.0'
gem 'dragonfly', '~> 0.9.12'
gem 'mongoid-grid_fs'

gem 'momentjs-rails', github: 'tkrotoff/momentjs-rails'

gem 'tabulous'

gem 'cocoon'
gem 'backbone-on-rails'

gem 'mustache'

gem 'gon'

gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'ruby-graphviz', :require => 'graphviz'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'twitter'

gem 'prawn'

gem "bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails", "~> 0.3.1.14"

gem 'country_select'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still have access to the old system, you should check the versions of the gems you had installed there;

```
gem list --local
```

And then do the same on the new system to compare. There may be required gems that are either absent or on the wrong version.

If you add the Cucumber output for the tests, and your env.rb file, we may be able to give more helpful answers.

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the requested files. I will try and obtain better cucumber output. I don't have access to the old machine any longer unfortunately, but this exact setup runs on other machines, so it is machine specific. I don't think it's something gem related, but obviously, I don't know what it is :(

Comment: I'd strongly suggest getting a gem list from another machine where it works. Aside from that, the cucumber output should give more indication as to what it's trying to do when the hangs happen.

Comment: Did you have any success?